# SPFx React webpart is not displaying all XML items from RSS News Feed

Tags: javascript, spfx, react, rss, typescript

I am currently building an RSS News Feed in SPFx using React as a framework and using an XML link https://feeds.expressen.se/nyheter/ (Swedish news if curious).

I can display all items, in this case title and author, in the console but in the webpart it only displays one item (the latest one).

I want to show all items in the webpart as well, that is a main purpose for an RSS Feed.

Here is how the webpart and console look like now (in Chrome):
[image]

Here is the code:
**RssApp.tsx**: (I am using a for loop to iterate over all items but it doesn't seem to work on the SPFx)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from '../RssApp.module.scss';
import { IRssAppProps } from './IRssAppProps';
import {IRssAppState} from './IRssAppState'

export default class RssApp extends React.Component<IRssAppProps, IRssAppState> {
  constructor(props: IRssAppProps){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        title: '',
        description: '',
        author: ''
    }
  }

  showSomeXML(){

      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){

          /**For loop iterating over items (i.e. all news article items) */
          for(let i = 0; i < xhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('item').length; i++){

            /***Showing in the console */
             console.log("Title: " + xhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('item')[i].children[3].innerHTML);
             console.log("Author: " + xhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('item')[i].children[2].innerHTML);   

             /**Set State to innerHTML from the xml file */
                this.setState(
                {  
                  title: xhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('item')[i].children[3].innerHTML,
                  author: xhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('item')[i].children[2].innerHTML
                })

          }
          console.log("News items: " + xhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('item').length);
          console.log(xhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('item')[1].children);
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", 'https://feeds.expressen.se/nyheter/', true);
      xhttp.send();
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    {this.showSomeXML()}
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IRssAppProps> {
    return (

              <div className={ styles.title }>{this.state.title}
                  <div>{this.state.description}</div>
                  <div>{this.state.author}</div>
              </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here are the states defined
**IRssAppState.ts**:

```
export interface IRssAppState{ 
    title: string;
    description: string;
    author: string;
}
```

Very strange since I do have a for loop iterating over all items and I do setState within the for loop.

Would appreciate all help I can get with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the problem is that your state is can and will show only one last item. You need to change it to be able to save an array in there:

```
export interface IRssItem{
    title: string;
    description: string;
    author: string;
}

export interface IRssAppState{ 
    items: IRssItem[];
}
```

Then:

```
showSomeXML(){

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
      let feedElementsArray:IRssItem[] = [];
      /**For loop iterating over items (i.e. all news article items) */
      for(let i = 0; i < xhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('item').length; i++){

        /***Showing in the console */
         console.log("Title: " + xhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('item')[i].children[3].innerHTML);
         console.log("Author: " + xhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('item')[i].children[2].innerHTML);   
         feedElementsArray.push({  
              title: xhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('item')[i].children[3].innerHTML,
              author: xhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('item')[i].children[2].innerHTML
            });


      }
      this.setState({
        items:feedElementsArray
      });
      console.log("News items: " + xhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('item').length);
      console.log(xhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('item')[1].children);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", 'https://feeds.expressen.se/nyheter/', true);
  xhttp.send();
```

}

And finally the render method where you render from the array:

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IRssAppProps> {
      const singleElement = (element:IRssItem)=>{
          return (
             <div className={ styles.title }>{element.title}
                <div>{element.description}</div>
                <div>{element.author}</div>
             </div>
          );
      };
      return (
          <div className='elementsContainer'>
              {this.state.items.map(singleElement)}
          </div>
      );
```

}

Hope it helps:)